# Seminorm - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

let $E=C([0,3])=\{f:[0,3]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid f \text{ is  continuous}\}$. Define $$\|f\| = \max_{x \in [1,2]} |f(x)|.$$

Prove that $\|f\|$ is a seminorm.

My attempt:

The first condition: $\|f\| \geq 0$. Well, it seems kinda obvious.

The second condition: I don't know if I can just assume that $$\|\lambda f\|=\max_{x \in [1,2]} |\lambda f(x)| = |\lambda| \max_{x \in [1,2]} |f(x)|=|\lambda|||f||.$$
We are working with continuous functions in a compact domain, so it seems "natural", but I still feel I'm missing some step.

The third condition: $$\max_{x \in[1,2]}|{f(x)+g(x)}|\leq \max_{x \in [1,2]} |f(x)|+ \max_{x \in [1,2]} |g(x)|.$$

I know that the triangle inequality holds for $\sup |f(x)+g(x)|\leq \sup |f(x)|+\sup |g(x)|$, can I just use the same logic?

Finally, how can I prove that this is not a norm? I'm trying to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is alright. A proof of the triangle inequality is completely the same. The difference is just that continuous functions attain their maximal values on a compact set. For counterexample just construct a continuous function on $[0,3]$ which is $0$ on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about construct a function, but it was a little bit hard to construct a continuous one.

Comment: A lot of examples are provided by piecewise linear functions.